# ordering results based on combine weightage of fields

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have a very interesting question for all you SQL masters out there.

As you all know that one of the prime requirement of any e-commerce based shopping cart is a good search.

Few days back, I got to know about MySQL full-text search, and I must say it's quiet interesting.

I want to go one step ahead in search query, and need to provide weightage to fields. These weightage would allow sorting of search result.

For example: I have following fields in product table

```
productid
name
description
price
```

'name' and 'description' fields are full-text indexed.

For any search keyword, query should look into both fields: name, description. But name field should have more weightage compared to description field.

Incase, if you haven't understand my question well, then following example should help.

```
 productid             name                   description                price
 1                  nice keyboard      this is a nice nice keyboard     10                
 2                  nice nice keyboard this is a nice nice keyboard     10                
 3                  keyboard           this is a nice keyboard     10
```

when search keyword is 'nice', and 'name' field have weightage: 10, and 'description' field have weightage: 1

for productid: 1, nice was found 1 (once) in name, 2 (twice) in description. so combine weightage is (1*10 + 2*1 = 10 + 2 = 12)

for productid: 2, nice was found 2 (twice) in name, 2 (twice) in description. so combine weightage is (2*10 + 2*1 = 20 + 2 = 22)

for productid: 3, nice was found 0 (none) in name, 1 (once) in description. so combine weightage is (0*10 + 1*1 = 0 + 1 = 1)

**2 questions**

(1) How can I provide weightage to a particular field? Do I need to create full-text index again to provide weightage?

(2) I need query, which can output results in desc. order of combine weightage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full text search can give you the relative relevance of the search:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT id,
    (MATCH(name) AGAINST ('nice')*10 ) + MATCH(description) AGAINST('nice') AS relevance
    FROM products
    WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('nice') OR
    MATCH(description) AGAINST ('nice')
) ORDER BY revelence DESC
```

By multiplying the name relevance by 10 I have skewed the relevance score towards that of names